# using python to compare lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have three lists in python. The first two contain strings and the third one contains ids that match the first one.

I would like to compare the strings from the second list with all the terms from the first list and when I find the same string I want to take the id from the third list and replace the string from the second list.

e.g.

```
list1 = ['hello, 'bye', 'third']
list2 = ['bye', 'second', 'forth']
list3 = [100, 150, 60]
```

as you can see the common term is `bye`. So I want to take the id from list3 (which is `150` and corresponds to the string in list1) and replace the `'bye'` string from list2 with this id.

Is there an easy way to do this with python?

Answer (score 2):

First, construct a dictionary mapping the strings in `list1` to the corresponding ids.  Then, use a list comprehension to apply the mapping:

```
list1 = ["hello", "bye", "third"]
list2 = ["bye", "second", "forth"]
list3 = [100, 150, 60] 
d = dict(zip(list1, list3))
print([d.get(x, x) for x in list2])
```

prints

```
[150, 'second', 'forth']
```